# How to set Date object to point to different time zone in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, timezone

In the code below I have used calendar object to initialize time Zone to GMT and get the time accordingly but when I put back in date object, its automatically converting to my local time zone i.e. IST.

```
Calendar gmt = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date dt=gmt.getTime();
```

Could anyone suggest a way through which I can retain the GMT format in date object also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> its automatically converting to my local time zone i.e. IST

No it's not. A `Date` object doesn't have a time zone - it's just an instant in time.

You'll see the system-local time zone if you call `toString()` on a `Date`, because that's unfortunately what `Date.toString()` does... but the time zone is not part of the information stored in a `Date`.

If you want to see a textual representation of a `Date` in a particular time zone, use `DateFormat` and set the time zone that you want to use.

Comment: I think that's the first time i beat you to it, Jon! \o/

Comment: When i debugged, inside the cdate its representing zoneinfo having ID "Asia/Calcutta". Does it not linked with the Date object?

Comment: @sunder: It's not part of the logical data in the `Date` object, no. It's an implementation detail used to avoid some arithmetic in some cases, but no - there's no such thing as "a `Date` in time zone X". It's best to ignore that implementation detail, as it's clearly misleading you.

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

The other answers are correct. The `toString` method silently applies your JVM’s current default time zone. This is one of many poor design choices in the old date-time classes. Dump those old classes. Move on to the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

An `Instant` is a moment on the time line in UTC.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to an `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Why are we bothering to create a `ZonedDateTime` in UTC if the `Instant` is already in UTC? Because a `ZonedDateTime` gives you flexibility in formatting String representations of the date-time values. The *java.time.format* package does not work with `Instant` objects.

A subclass of `ZoneId`, `ZoneOffset`, has a constant for UTC.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(  ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Adjust into any desired time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

### Use proper time zone names

Avoid using 3-4 letter codes for time zones. They are neither standardized nor unique. By `IST` did you mean *India Standard Time* or *Irish Standard Time*?

Use [standard time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Most are in the pattern of continent/region. For India, [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata). For Ireland, [`Europe/Dublin`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Dublin).

Comment: Good addition. I have not yet figured out though what 'the standard' for time zone naming really is: IANA, TZ, Olson, TimeZoneInfo? You are claiming that TZ is the standard but I doubt that's settled.

Answer (score 1):

The Date class does not represent a timezone. It's toString method uses the default platform time zone to output a human readable timestamp, internally it's just a long.